# Dotted border near checkbox IE9

Tags: css, extjs, checkbox, internet-explorer-9, outline

I use EXT.Js framework and i got an issue with IE9(in IE8 and previous versions all works fine): a dotted border near all checkboxes when click on it.
I tried to set in main css file:

```
body.ext-ie input{
    outline: none;
}
```

But it does not work.

I think its about a label associeted with my checkbox, but i don't really know, how to fix it.

An example of my issue:

[image: wrong behavior in red]

ExtJs code, that generate this checkbox is:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'XXXX XXXX',    
    name: 'XXXX',                
    xtype: 'checkbox',    
    disabled: !isXXXXX}
```

A css file is available here: [css file](http://pastebin.com/VW7PLm3J)

**UPD 1**

I've corrected the ExtJS file as below: JS:

```
items [{
    fieldLabel: 'xxx',    
    name: 'xxx',                
    xtype: 'checkbox', 
    style: {outline: 'none'}, 
    onfocus: function() {this.style.outline = "none"; }
 }]
```

it generetes the following html:

```
<div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen271" style="width: 180px;">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1161" name="persistentRecoveryEnabled" class=" x-form- 
 checkbox x-form-field" style="outline: none;" checked="">
  <label for="ext-comp-1161" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen272">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

in a Document Mode Quirks Mode(Page default) dotted line appears around the "x-form-cb-label".

in a Document Mode IE9 Standarts  dotted line doesn't appear with this settings.

CSS modification doesn't help at all.

So, there are two questions:

1. how to set a style to the `class="x-form-cb-label"` via JS?
2. how to set Document Mode IE9 Standarts as Page Default via JS? (html is genereted by ExtJS)

Comment: Show us your HTML/CSS or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VW7PLm3J a css file.

Comment: @ProtosZetZ And what about the HTML? It would be better if you included them in the original question.

Comment: As i know all html is generated by ExtJs. I can not find *html file anywhere in all project. All, what i have is css and ExtJs files.
Also, i'll update my question with ExtJs code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suspect, it's an `outline` around the `label` of your field.

The reason your code to hide the `outline` isn't working is because you're specifying the outline one the field, not the label.

(though given the code you've shown us, I wonder why it's a blank space rather than saying `XXXX XXXX`?)

If you want to hide it, you should use `label` as your selector rather than `input`:

```
label {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Before you do that though, it's worth pointing out, that the dotted outline around the currently selected field is an important feature for some users. In particular, disabled users who can't use a mouse rely on it when navigating a site using the keyboard so that they can tell where they are on a page.

If you hide, it you will be actively discriminating against those users. (depending on your site audience this may not particularly matter to you, but beware that it is illegal in some countries)

Comment: I tried use `label`, but it does not works. Investigation shows, that IE9 added several parameters about `label`, for example `outline-width` set to `medium`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
label:focus
{
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used css like `style='background:#fff;border:none;'` and it's worked fine for removing the border around checkboxes in ie9.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have [formated](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.